# Using System.Xml.Linq with mono command line compilers

Tags: xml, linq, mono

With the following code in C#/Mono,

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

I got this error.

```
 error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Linq' does not exist in the namespace `System.Xml'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

What assembly reference do I need to use System.Xml.Linq with mono?

```
dmcs /r:???? main.cs
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be:

```
dmcs -r:System.Xml.Linq.dll main.cs
```

Comment: It definitely exists https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/System.Xml.Linq/

Answer (score 3):

I received the same error when trying to load System.Xml.Linq in [CSharpRepl](http://mono-project.com/CsharpRepl).

You can specify the same command line argument as the first answer:

```
csharp -r:System.Xml.Linq.dll
```

Or you can load the assembly from within the REPL itself:

```
csharp> LoadAssembly("System.Xml.Linq.dll");
csharp> using System.Xml.Linq;
```