# emacs F# mode REPL :: using Linq

Tags: linq, emacs, f#

I am using [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) in Ubuntu precise and have installed F# following the instructions found [here](http://functional-variations.net/crossplatform/).
I have also installed [fsharp mode for emacs](http://laurent.le-brun.eu/site/index.php/2010/06/25/58-new-fsharp-mode-for-emacs) and so am able to test and compile simple F# programs (both on **emacs F# mode REPL** and also generate executables which I run under mono).

However, the statement:

```
open System.Xml.Linq
```

fails in both the **emacs F# mode REPL** and when invoking **fsharpc** from the bash shell with the same error:

```
error FS0039: The namespace 'Linq' is not defined
```

I found a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088186/using-system-xml-linq-with-mono-command-line-compilers) in SO for C#, and although the advise to use "-r: System.Xml.Linq" does works for the compilation from the shell:

```
fsharpc -r:System.Xml.Linq.dll parseemails.fs
```

... I still can't figure out how to make the Linq namespace available to emacs F# mode REPL so I can use it with C-c C-e evaluations.

Comment: Does using `#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll"` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by John in a comment, if you want to reference an assembly in the F# interactive (the REPL running in emacs mode), you can do that using:

```
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll"
```

When compiling code, this command is not valid and you have to add the command line argument `-r:System.Xml.Linq.dll`. If you want to combine both (run interactively and compile the same code), you can use conditional compilation:

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll"
#endif
```

The symbol `INTERACTIVE` is defined automatically in the REPL mode, so if you select and run these three lines, it should reference the assembly (but it will not break your code when compiling).